# how to handle both apostrophes and quotation marks conversion in string

Tags: javascript

how to handle both apostrophes  and quotation marks conversion together in string

Currently i am handleing only apostrophes

```
 var strname = data[i].name
strname = strname.replace("'","@");
```

and how to i replace it back later
strrename = strrename.replace("@","'");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want to do here but if you're trying to replace single quotes and double quotes in a string with the @ symbol then this should work:

```
var strname = data[i].name.replace("'","@").replace("\"","@");
```

Comment: how do i repalce it back to apostrophes and quotation .      currently i am using strrename = strrename.replace("@","'");

Comment: @Guddi: If you want to accurately change them back to their original values, you'll have to use something other than the @ symbol for the double quote. For example, change the end to something like `.replace("\"","|")`. Then, to change them back you can use: `var strname = data[i].name.replace("@","'").replace("|","\"");` But a warning: be careful because if the `data[i].name` already contains these characters, they will get replaced as well.

Answer (score 1):

Doing two replaces is expensive and unnecessary …

```
strname = strname.replace(/["']/g, "@");
```

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

Comment: Do you have supporting materials that show the regexp solution is faster (especially for small strings and few replaced characters)?

Comment: @OskarBerggren, as of 2015 the accepted answer is faster: http://jsperf.com/replace-apos

Answer (score 0):

Just like you handle apostrophes.

```
strname.
    replace('"', 'what_you_want_quotes_to_be_replaced_with').
    replace("'", 'what_you_want_apostrophes_to_be_replaced_with');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strname = strname.replace("'","@");
strname = strname.replace("\"","@");
```

Comment: var strname = data[i].name strname = strname.replace("'","@");

Comment: strrename = strrename.replace("@","'");